# Converting a dataframe with a character vector as a column into longform

Tags: r, transformation, rds

I was hoping somebody could help me with a problem I'm having with an exercise on the DataCamp "Building Web Applications with Shiny in R" course, specifically with transforming one of the datasets they use in the exercise.

I've imported their dataset (RDS) using the readRDS function and it looks like this:

```
 $ id         : int  10259 25693 20130 22213 13162 6602 42779 3735 16903 12734 ...
 $ cuisine    : chr  "greek" "southern_us" "filipino" "indian" ...
 $ ingredients:List of 39774
  ..$ : chr  "romaine lettuce" "black olives" "grape tomatoes" "garlic" ...
  ..$ : chr  "plain flour" "ground pepper" "salt" "tomatoes" ...
  ..$ : chr  "eggs" "pepper" "salt" "mayonaise" ...
  ..$ : chr  "water" "vegetable oil" "wheat" "salt"
  ..$ : chr  "black pepper" "shallots" "cornflour" "cayenne pepper" ...
  ..$ : chr  "plain flour" "sugar" "butter" "eggs" ...
  ..$ : chr  "olive oil" "salt" "medium shrimp" "pepper" ...
  ..$ : chr  "sugar" "pistachio nuts" "white almond bark" "flour" ...
  ..$ : chr  "olive oil" "purple onion" "fresh pineapple" "pork" ...
  ..$ : chr  "chopped tomatoes" "fresh basil" "garlic" "extra-virgin olive oil" ...
```

In their tutorial, they have a dataset that's been transformed so that there are three columns, id, cuisine and ingredients, but ingredients only has one ingredient (meaning there are multiple rows for the same id).

Usually when I have to do something like this, I use the dplyr function 'gather', but this won't work in this instance as it is for gathering multiple columns, rather than spitting up a column containing character vectors of varying length. I also tried to use the separate() function, but this requires you to specify what columns you want to separate the vectors into, which I can't do as they all vary in length.

If somebody could give me an idea as to how I'd go about transforming the above dataframe so that it's longform, I'd be very grateful.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for `spread`: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html. This effectively does the opposite of `gather`.

Should also be mentioned that `gather` and `spread` are no longer being updated, having been replaced with their arguably more explicit counterparts `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html and https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html. Datacamp may not have updated their courses to reflect this however.